# change scene with a button and also do it with an effect? Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and my goal is not to make a game, but a mobile application, I don't use the Android SDK because I need to do something with augmented reality and I need to do it with Unity, it's getting quite complicated because I'm not familiar or with the language or with anything, in short, I was able to change scenes by means of a button, like a log that verifies things, but Unity does not have a scene transition effect or something similar, I saw several videos where it can be done a transition, effects and so on, but they are for when you touch a button or touch the screen in this case, I would like to know if there is the possibility of being able to implement an effect after it effectively validates the information and then makes a translation effect to the other scene, is this possible, thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync
```

[Unity SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync manual](https://SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync)

for loading scene while you run your own transition. Fade in/out is the most common transition for such occasions.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, I will try to find out how to do it and implement it, in short, the only thing I need is an effect when I change the scene, it does not matter how to achieve it as long as it looks good. Thanks.